# ReactJs And Firestore: Properties of mapped objects are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a list of UserNames in my SignUp class to only allow creation of a unique displayNames. However when trying to view the displayName of the object as below, in the console I can see displayName when the initial object is mapped, but trying to store it as a variable gives me undefined for the value.

```
function nameCheck(){
    let userList = [];
    db.collection("userNames").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data()) //I can see the parameter displayName here with //proper value
          console.log(doc.displayName) //here it is being logged as undefined 
        });
        console.log(userList); //I can see the array has the right amount of objects, but they are all //undefined 


    });
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't get it to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to say:

```
console.log(doc.data().displayName)
```

The values of the document properties are in the object returned by `data()`.

Comment: On Stack overflow, it's customary to upvote and mark correct the answer that were helpful.